# Convert integer to string, floating point to integer in a list? And print the list

Tags: python-2.7

How to convert an integer to string and a floating point to integer in a list?

I tried something like that:

```
list=[1,3.14,"something"]
print(map(str,list[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the list:

```
list=[1,3.14,"something"]
```

**Converting  the integer to string:**

```
list[0] = str(list[0])
```

**Converting the floating point number to integer:**

This will give only the integer part of the float:

```
list[1] = int(round(list[1]))
```

This will round the number before converting to integer:

```
list[1] = int(round(list[1]))
```

**Printing the list...**

```
print(list)
```

Output

```
['1', 3, 'something']
```